# C++ substr() method seems to return 0 when used

Tags: c++, sorting, struct

I'm writing a program that will read in a file of 5 Buddy Holly albums, sort them alphabetically, sort the songs within each album alphabetically, and then print the album name, year it came out, and the sorted list of songs. The catch here is that I'm supposed to keep the number next to the song so it comes out like so:

```
Buddy Holly 
1958
10.  Baby I Don't Care
 7.  Everyday
 1.  I'm Gonna Love You Too
 4.  Listen to Me
12.  Little Baby
 3.  Look at Me
 8.  Mailman, Bring Me No More Blues
 2.  Peggy Sue 
11.  Rave On!
 6.  Ready Teddy 
 5.  Valley of Tears 
 9.  Words of Love
```

The problem comes when I try to sort the songs. My professor recommended I use the `substr()` method to skip past the first 4 characters in the string to start the comparison at the first letter, but when I use it, it keeps giving me this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::substr: __pos (which is 4) > this->size() (which is 0)
```

I went back and tried the `.size()/length()` method to see if I got positive values(I did), and I also set an int equal to that value, then tried an if statement to see if that int was greater than 0. It was not. 
I'm honestly at a loss of what to do here, this is the very last thing I need to do to finish the thing.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <istream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define a 5
using namespace std;

struct buddyH
{
  string albumName;
  string year;
  string songs[12];
  int count;
};


int main()
  {
    buddyH bh[a], thd;
    string st, jam;
    bool change = true, change2 = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
    { //start read-in  for loop
        int k = 0;
        getline(cin, bh[i].albumName);
        getline(cin, bh[i].year);
        while (getline(cin, st))
          {
            if (st[0] == '=') break;
            bh[i].songs[k] = st;
            k++;
          }
        bh[i].count = k;
    }//end read-in  for loop

   while(change)
   {
    change = false;
     for(int j = 0; j < a-1; j++)
     {
        if(bh[j].albumName > bh[j+1].albumName)
        {

           thd = bh[j];
           bh[j] = bh[j+1];
           bh[j+1] = thd;
           change = true;
        }
     }
  }

  while(change2)
  {
    int chk1, chk2;
    change2 = false;
    for(int x = 0; x < a; x++)
    {
      int s = sizeof(bh[x].songs)/sizeof(bh[x].songs[0]);
      for(int y = 0; y < s-1; y++)
      {

        if(bh[x].songs[y].substr(4) > bh[x].songs[y+1].substr(4))
        {
          jam = bh[x].songs[y];
          bh[x].songs[y] = bh[x].songs[y+1];
          bh[x].songs[y+1] = jam;
          change2 = true;
        }
      }
   }
 }


  for(int c = 0; c < a; c++)
  {
     cout << bh[c].albumName << endl;
     cout << bh[c].year << endl;

     for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
     {
          cout << bh[c].songs[i] << endl;
     }
     cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Input File:

```
That'll Be the Day 
1958 
 1.  You Are My One Desire
 2.  Blue Days, Black Nights
 3.  Modern Don Juan
 4.  Rock Around With Ollie Vee
 5.  Ting A Ling
 6.  Girl On My Mind
 7.  That'll Be the Day
 8.  Love Me
 9.  I'm Changing All Those Changes
10.  Don't Come Back Knockin'
11.  Midnight Shift
========================
Buddy Holly 
1958
 1.  I'm Gonna Love You Too
 2.  Peggy Sue
 3.  Look at Me
 4.  Listen to Me
 5.  Valley of Tears
 6.  Ready Teddy 
 7.  Everyday
 8.  Mailman, Bring Me No More Blues
 9.  Words of Love
10.  Baby I Don't Care
11.  Rave On!
12.  Little Baby
======================== 
The Buddy Holly Story
1959 
 1.  Raining In My Heart
 2.  Early in the Morning
 3.  Peggy Sue
 4.  Maybe Baby
 5.  Everyday
 6.  Rave On!
 7.  That'll Be the Day
 8.  Heartbeat
 9.  Think It Over
10.  Oh, Boy!
11.  It's So Easy!
12.  It Doesn't Matter Anymore
======================== 
The Buddy Holly Story, Vol. 2 
1960
 1.  Peggy Sue Got Married
 2.  Well, All Right
 3.  What to Do
 4.  That Makes It Tough
 5.  Now We're One
 6.  Take Your Time
 7.  Crying, Waiting, Hoping
 8.  True Love Ways
 9.  Learning the Game
10.  Little Baby
11.  Moondreams
12.  That's What They Say
======================== 
Reminiscing
1963
 1.  Reminiscing
 2.  Slippin' and Slidin'
 3.  Bo Diddley
 4.  Wait 'Till the Sun Shines, Nellie
 5.  Baby, Won't You Come Out Tonight
 6.  Brown Eyed Handsome Man
 7.  Because I Love You
 8.  It's Not My Fault
 9.  I'm Gonna Set My Foot Down
10.  Changing All Those Changes
11.  Rock-A-Bye Rock
```

Comment: Are you sure that `bh[x].songs[y].length >=4 && bh[x].songs[y+1].length() >= 4`? You can put an assert on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you access the array of songs which has no element inside (empty string).

May I ask what is the purpose of this line?

```
int s = sizeof(bh[x].songs)/sizeof(bh[x].songs[0]);
```

if you are trying to find the total number of songs, then replace that line with this line:

```
int s = bh[x].count;
```

I tried with your code and it works. Your program successfully sorts the songs name as you described.

Your program crashes when it substr(4) an empty string because not all the string in the songs array  is filled. Some of your albums only contain 11 songs.

Comment: Oh wow, that completely solved it. Yes, I was trying to find the number of songs in each album. I just thought that bh[x].count would count how many _albums_ there were instead of songs. You've been a great help!

Comment: Do you think giving direct answers to homework really helps the person asking in the long run?